# Stop reloading of UITableViewCell when cell reappears!

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Within this method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

If I call a `NSLog` it will print out that log when the `UITableViewCell` shows on the screen every time. I was just wondering if it's possible to load this cell once and not reload it every time it appears again. I understand that this isn't a very efficient design but it's just on the one cell I need to do it on!

Thanks

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve where you think this would be beneficial to you?

Comment: Just posted a comment on the answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  You can create your cell(s) once, say in viewDidLoad:, and return it from tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:.  cellForRowAtIndexPath will still be called, but you're only creating/initializing your cell once.  If you like you could create all your cells this way and store them in an array.  Don't forget to release these cells when the view unloads.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _myCachedCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewStylePlain reuseIdentifier: nil];
    _myCachedCell.textLabel.text = @"some text";
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ( indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0 )
        return _myCachedCell;
```

Comment: I'm not claiming its a good idea or not.  The question stated he understood this isn't the best design.  But, if you have a TableView with a limited number of fixed cells, this can be a quick and easy way to get what you need.

Comment: It should work fine with any cell type - custom or not.  Something else is wrong.